# Using SAF File Picker in Android 10 (Q) to copy files from Downloads to local app folder

Tags: java, android

Since Android 10 (API 29) I need to use the Storage Access Framework's File Picker to select GPX (GPS) files to copy from the Downloads folder to my local app folder. I have implemented the file picker and am able to select the GPX file, however the result data URI appears different to the filename (but unique) and I cannot seem to use it to copy the files. The rest of the code is the same "copy" code I used in previous versions of Android. What am I doing wrong and how should I best use the SAF File Picker to copy files? I haven't been able to find a recent (API 29) "file copy" example on the net...

```
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
...
public void performFileSearch() {         
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);       
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                // intent.setType("application/gpx");   // Filters GPX file but wont let me select them.
                intent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
...
if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                handleDownloadedGPXFiles2(uri);
            }
        }
...
private void handleDownloadedGPXFiles2(Uri selectedFileUri) {
        File sourceFile = new File(selectedFileUri.getPath());     // Returns a unique number or string but NOT filename string???
        File destDirectory = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Imported");
        File destFile = new File(destDirectory, "test.gpx");       // Needs to be same name as original filename.
        try {
            if (!destFile.exists()) {
                destFile.createNewFile();
            }
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
            FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Import Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Comment: `I haven't been able to find a recent (API 29) "file copy" example on the net...` That is not recent. They are all over the place since lollipop.

Comment: `however the result data URI appears different to the filename (but unique) ` Yes that happens. Especially from the Download folder. Search for how to `query()` the content resolver for `DISPLAY_NAME`.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the file? If you can copy the file using the content resolver you could also read the file directly using the contentresolver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File sourceFile = new File(selectedFileUri.getPath());
```

Remove above line.

```
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
```

Replace that line by:

```
InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedFileUri);
```

Further you can remove

```
       if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }
```

as the file will be created by the `new FileOutputStream();`

Finally: Your last Toast() is on the wrong place. It should be in the `try` block.

Place a different Toast() in the catch block to inform yourself or the user.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks blackapps. Final code works well...

```
    private void handleDownloadedGPXFiles2(Uri selectedFileUri) {

        String displayName = "imported.gpx";
        String fileExtension;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedFileUri, null, null, null, null);
                try {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        if (displayName != null && displayName.length() >=4) {
                            fileExtension = displayName.substring(displayName.length() - 4);
                            if (!fileExtension.equals(".gpx")){
                                myCustomToast("Must be a .GPX file!");
                                return;
                            }
                        } else {
                                myCustomToast("Must be a .GPX file!");
                                return;
                        }
                    }
                    File destDirectory = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Imported");
                    File destFile = new File(destDirectory, displayName);
                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                    InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedFileUri);
                    OutputStream out = outStream;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Import Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Import FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
    }
```

Comment: Good you found how to tackle the display name.

Comment: For the extension. Nicer: `if ( !displayName.endsWith(".gpx")) return;`

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Import FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` People want to know the reason. `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File copy FAILED\n\nIOException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`