# Read selected file using Android Storage Access Framework

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Android's Storage Access Framework in a Xamarin application to allow the user to save SQLite3 files to the SD card and also open files from the SD card.

To save the file:

```
Intent save = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
save.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
save.SetType("application/*");
save.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, "database.db3");
StartActivityForResult(save, 40);
```

How can I save an existing db3 file instead of creating this new empty one?

To open the file:

```
Intent read = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
read.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
read.SetType("application/*");
StartActivityForResult(read, 50);
```

When the file is opened how do I access it in the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SAF File Picker in Android 10 (Q) to copy files from Downloads to local app folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899075/using-saf-file-picker-in-android-10-q-to-copy-files-from-downloads-to-local-ap)

Comment: Basically you get back a `Uri` in your `onActivityResult` (the old way of doing it) and then you can get and input or output stream from the Uri and then you can write/read your data from these streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Access documents and other files from shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files). On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, you cannot use the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent action to request access to the following directories:

- The root directory of the internal storage volume.
- The root directory of each SD card volume that the device
  manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card
  is emulated or removable. A reliable volume is one that an app can
  successfully access most of the time.
- The Download directory.

You can use the `FileOutputStream` and here is the sample about [How to properly save a file in a shared folder in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996028/how-to-properly-save-a-file-in-a-shared-folder-in-xamarin)